# Head to head movement and features in Minimalism

Tags: syntax, minimalism

Consider 2 heads a and b. b moves to head a.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lGdSevs.png]

Does the feature [X] get on a1 by virtue of b merging to a2 by head movement?

Is this kind of feature percolation still allowed in the Minimalist program?

I'd appreciate some citations on this if possible, it seems hard to find on the internet.

Comment: What are a_1 and a_2 exactly?  Did b raise and adjoin to a?  I believe whatever your question may be, it has a trivial answer. But as it stands, it is ill-formed.

Comment: It's not a trivial answer, and it's not ill-formed, sorry. I found the answer alone. See here for a description of the view: books.google.com/books?id=xJVKWJpZpbkC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=hornstein+label+union+features&source=bl&ots=bpbxNbfhC4&sig=1J5d5o7N6abzNzPBJ_T1B0SJLiY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAWoVChMI7pzPrJ3OxwIVyoksCh0EgAS_#v=onepage&q=hornstein%20label%20union%20features&f=false